# What does this syntax [0:1:5] mean (do) in the context of the given code?

Tags: matlab, syntax, octave

I don't understand how `[0:1:5]` is being used in the code below:

```
function [x , y] = plotTrajectory(Vo,O,t,g)
% calculating x and y values
x = Vo * cos(O) * t ;
y = Vo*(sin(O)*t)-(0.5*g*(t.^2));
plot (x,y);
hold on
end

for i = (0: (pi/8): pi);
[x,y] = plotTrajectory(10,i,[0:1:5],9.8);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the parameters are being used to find particular `X` and `Y` values.  `O` changes from 0 to `pi` in steps of `pi/8` while `Vo`, `t` and `g` remain unchanged.

The `t` variable is simply an array from 0 to 5 in steps of 1 and so there are 6 time points defined all together.  With these time points and with a particular value of `O`, but with the values of `Vo`, `t` and `g` being held constant throughout this entire endeavour, 6 `X` and `Y` points are defined and are thus plotted on a graph.  A graph is generated for each value of `O` and thus a set of 6 different `X` and `Y` points are generated. Each graph with each value of `O` are all plotted on the same graph.

We can rewrite the above code in pseudo-code to make it easier to understand as follows:

```
 for i = 0, pi/8, 2*pi/8, ..., pi
     define Vo = 10
     define O = i
     define t = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
     define g = 9.8
     run function plotTrajectory(Vo, O, t, g)
 end

 function plotTrajectory(Vo, O, t, g)
     calculate x = Vo * cos(O) * t, for t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
     calculate y = Vo * (sin(O) * t) - (0.5 * g * t^2), for t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
     plot x and y for t = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 on the same graph
 end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation!  This makes a lot more sense for me.